# R: Why 454044 - 264347.07 returns 189696.9 and not 189696.93?

Tags: r

Using R:Why 454044 - 264347.07 returns 189696.9 and not 189696.93?

What do I need to do to get the correct answer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Set `options(digits = 8)`.  By default, R only prints 7 digits in numerics.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that it's just a display issue. If you store the value (i.e., x <- 454044 - 264347.07), the correct value to the hundredths place is stored in x, even if it is only shown to the tenths place when it prints to the console. You can confirm this easily in RStudio, or by changing the options as stated by Richard above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
formatC(454044 - 264347.07,digits=2, format="f")

OR

Set options(digits = 8)
It will show:
"189696.93"

Comment: OP wants a numeric back.  `formatC()` gives a character.

Comment: yes, if want numeric then set digit to 8 or whatever you want to set